# Find the current execution point in Delphi at runtime

Tags: delphi, debugging

I've written a delphi program, which has grown to some complexitiy. Now I'm facing the problem, that I introduced somewhere an infinite loop, but I can't find the location. The program is a realtime application and hang up indefinitely. Is there a possibility to pause the exectution and find out, where my program currently is?

When I use the pause button of the delphi debugger, it always breaks in the cpu-window at a line called `ntdll.RtlUserThreadStart`, seems to be some kind of os method, but I have no idea what that means. Even stepping through the assembler doesn't return me in any line of my code. Is there a possibility to say the debugger to stop at an arbitary line in my code, where it's executing?

Comment: Be sure that you're on the right thread when you pause (Ctrl+Alt+T).

Comment: Yes, I was in the wrong thread ... didn't know there is a thread window. Thank you very much! It works fine.

Comment: You're welcome! Posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The debugger might be showing the stack trace of a different thread then what you expect when you pause the program. You can check that from the "Thread Status" window (Ctrl+Alt+T).

Answer (score 9):

When you pause in the debugger, it won't necessarily show you the "main" thread, but *all* the threads will be paused. Use the thread debug window to select a different thread.

The current execution point might not be in your code. Use the call-stack debug window to see how your program got to where it is and to select which point in the stack you're interested in. You can use the "step out" command to leave the current function and go back up to the caller. That's useful when the debugger pauses your program in a library function that you don't have the source for.

Comment: What does "whatever thread happened to be active" mean? On a multi-core machine, more than one thread may be active.

Comment: Fair enough, @David. Even on a single-core machine, the debugger can't really show the active thread since at the time things get paused, the *debugger itself* is the active thread. Ultimately I don't really know how the debugger chooses which thread to show. Most recently active? Most recently triggered an event the debugger is interested in (such as creating a thread, loading a library, or passing a breakpoint)?

Comment: Anyway, it matters not. I've always wondered why breaking into a running program behaved in this way, and I've always found other ways to discern what the thread of interest was doing. It seems so obvious now that it's been pointed out, so thanks to you and Sertac for doing so and +1 to you both.